# How can I list custom post by custom category?

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, query-posts

From some references I wrote a code for create custom post type (**journal**) and taxonomy using following code. It works fine. Next I am add a new category from admin side for my custom post type (**journal**) called **featured**. I can sort this post type by category on admin side [image: Admin part]. But on user side I can't list them when I am list my category which shows only **post categories** Like below image. Below image show list of my custom post type(**journal**) . How can I show this journal list by category name on user side?[image]

```
function post_type_journal()
    {

        $labels = array(
        'name' => _x('Journals', 'post type general name'),
        'singular_name' => _x('Journal', 'post type singular name'),
        'add_new' => _x('Add New', 'journal'),
        'add_new_item' => __('Add New Journal'),
        'edit_item' => __('Edit Journal'),
        'new_item' => __('New Journal'),
        'view_item' => __('View Journal'),
        'search_items' => __('Search Journal'),
        'not_found' =>  __('Nothing found'),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __('Nothing found in Trash'),
        'parent_item_colon' => ''
    );

    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'public' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'menu_icon' => null,
        'rewrite' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'menu_position' => null,
        'supports' => array('title','editor','thumbnail'),

      ); 
        register_post_type('journal', $args);
    }
    add_action('init','post_type_journal');
function themes_taxonomy() {

        register_taxonomy('article', 'journal', array(
        // Hierarchical taxonomy (like categories)
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'query_var' => true,        
        // This array of options controls the labels displayed in the WordPress Admin UI
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => _x( 'Journal Category', 'taxonomy general name' ),
            'singular_name' => _x( 'Journal-Category', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
            'search_items' =>  __( 'Search Journal-Categories' ),
            'all_items' => __( 'All Journal-Categories' ),
            'parent_item' => __( 'Parent Journal-Category' ),
            'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Journal-Category:' ),
            'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Journal-Category' ),
            'update_item' => __( 'Update Journal-Category' ),
            'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Journal-Category' ),
            'new_item_name' => __( 'New Journal-Category Name' ),
            'menu_name' => __( 'Journal Categories' ),
        ),

        'rewrite' => array(
            'slug' => 'article', // This controls the base slug that will display before each term
            'with_front' => false, // Don't display the category base before "/locations/"            
            'hierarchical' => true // This will allow URL's like "/locations/boston/cambridge/"
        ),
    ));
}
add_action( 'init', 'themes_taxonomy',0);
```

The following is code of user side that outputs is shown in second image

```
$categories = get_categories($args);
  foreach($categories as $category) { 
    echo '<p>Category: <a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $category->name ) . '" ' . '>' . $category->name.'</a> </p> ';
    echo '<p> Description:'. $category->description . '</p>';
    echo '<p> Post Count: '. $category->count . '</p>';  } 


        $type = 'journal';
                echo  $cat_id=get_cat_ID('featured');
        $args=array(
                 'cat'=>$cat_id,
         'post_type' => $type,
         'post_status' => 'publish',
         'posts_per_page' => -1,
         'caller_get_posts'=> 1);

        $my_query = null;
        $my_query = new WP_Query($args);
        if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
         while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
            <p><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></p>
        <?php
          endwhile;
        }
        wp_reset_query();  // Restore global post data stomped by the_post().
        ?>
```

Comment: Please don't ignore answers [to your older questions](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/131466/how-can-i-add-single-catogory-for-custom-post-type). Comment and if you got a solution, then mark it as such. Else people will stay back from answering your later questions.

Answer (score 0):

Using categories isn't the same as using a custom taxonomy. You should adapt your code to use `get_terms` and to query for your [custom tax](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters):

```
$categories = get_terms('article');
  foreach($categories as $category) { 
    $args=array(
     'article'=>$category->slug,
     'post_type' => 'journal',
     'post_status' => 'publish',
     'posts_per_page' => -1,
     'caller_get_posts'=> 1);
  }
```